# Set of repeated NaNs in pandas Series

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, equality

I want to check if a column of a dataframe contains more than one different value, so I take the column, make it a set, and check its length. But I'm having an issue with NaNs. I expected that the length of a column with all NaNs would be zero but this is not the case, why?

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan

set([nan, nan, nan]) # set has one element
set(pd.Series([nan, nan, nan])) #set has three elements
```

The same would happen with a numpy array:

```
set(pd.np.array([nan, nan, nan])) #set has three elements
```

This doesn't happen with other values:

```
set(pd.np.array([1,1,1])) #set has one element
```

Comment: You can just call [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to get a count of non-NaN values, also this isn't a bug, you're effectively creating a series of 3 `NaN` values, calling `set` on this will have no affect on a `Series` there are other methods such as `value_counts` for counting and ignoring `NaN` values

Comment: The same thing would happen if you created a numpy array of 3 `NaN values

Comment: you are right it happens with a numpy array, it doesn't happen with a regular list. The thing is that I am not looking after counting NaN's but identifying if an array has more than one different element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare [nunique](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.Series.count.html) to [count](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.Series.count.html):

```
s1 = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, 1, 1, 2])
s2 = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, 3])

>>> s1.count() == s1.nunique()
False

>>> s2.count() == s2.nunique()
True
```

Both methods exclude all non-NA/null observations.

Comment: I think nunique is what I'm looking for, if i'm correct it counts the number of different elements in a Series, ignoring NaN's?

Answer (score 2):

### Object identity in the Python world

```
>>> L = [nan, nan, nan]
>>> L[0] is L[1]
True
```

### Non-Python values in a dataframe are copies

```
>>> s = pd.Series([nan, nan, nan])
>> s[0] is s[1]
False
```

### NaNs are consistently not equal

```
>>> s[0] == s[1]
False

>>> L[0] == L[1]
False
```